# Загрузить нужный .properties файл в зависимости от ОС Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties

Есть два конфигурационных файла для разных ОС `windows.properties` и `unix.properties`.

Есть конфигурация:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "storage")
public class StorageProperties {

    private String root;
    private String sitesDirName;
    private String avatarsDirName;
    private String screenshotsDirName;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {

    }

}
```

Как сделать так что бы определенный файл загружался в зависимости от ОС?
Я натыкался на `@Conditional`, но это одно условие. Может с ним как-то сделать можно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String osName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
Resource resource;
if(osName.contains("windows")){
   resource = new ClassPathResource("/windows.properties");
} else {
   resource = new ClassPathResource("/unix.properties");
}
Properties props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
```

---

но можно воспользоваться и `profile`

они назначаются аргументом `-Dspring.profiles.active`

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=windows
-Dspring.profiles.active=unix
```

Они определяют какой файл `application.properties` взять для инициализации. Поэтому рядом с ним необходимо положить ещё 2 файла `application-windows.properties` и `application-unix.properties` они наследуют все поля файла `application.properties` и могут как иметь дополнительные аттрибуты, так и перезаписывать.

А дальше можно заинжектить значение

```
@Value(${your.variable.name.in.properties:defaultValue})
private String myVar;
```

Comment: Для этого же ведь надо указывать аргумент при запуске. Это как вариант. А если брать конфигурацию. то никак?

Comment: Хорошо. Если брать профиля. Как мне конфиг сделать в Java коде? то бишь будет для одинаковых класса, но с разным названием и аннотацией `@Profile`?

Comment: `@Profile` не нужно, нет, просто будет 3 файла с разными названиями properties в ресурсах лежать. А обращаться к ним можно например через `@Value(${your.variable.name.in.properties:defaultValue})`. Аннотация заинжектит значение в переменную

Comment: вроде так как написал, тоже должно сработать

Comment: Спасибо. решил заюзать профиля.