# Как передать аргументы в приложение через pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

Как в приложение передать VM options 
`-DmyPropertyName=D:/project/src/main/resources/testing.properties` через Pom.xml?

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
```

При тестировании в IDEA я передаю, как просто VM опцию. Но при тестировании через maven, как сделать, чтобы `testing.properties` настроек автоматически передавался в мое приложение?

Comment: Существует огромное колисество способов для передачи параметров https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите передать аргументы для `spring-boot-maven-plugin`, то у него есть конфигурация

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <jvmArguments>
        -DmyPropertyName=D:/project/src/main/resources/testing.properties
      </jvmArguments>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: тесты не проходят.`"Failed to load ApplicationContext"...` Может путь к файлу, как-то по другому указывается здесь?

Comment: а почему вы именно так хотите передать properties, смотрели ли вы в сторону profile?

Comment: не смотрел, а с profile как?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Comment: тут ещё описываю их https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/929664/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-properties-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%9E%D0%A1-spring-boot/929673#929673

Comment: тогда аргумент будет `-Dspring.active.profiles=testing`